# How to print/log an Apache HttpClient request query string

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Is it possible to get hold of the actual query string that will be used for a HttpClient request (HttpPost, HttpGet etc.) either prior to or after calling `client.execute(request)`?

I'd like to do this because my request is failing and I want to debug the actual query string that's being used (it's an S3 file upload using HttpPost, so the parameters are complex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you've tried it, but the HTTP Client library has some logging settings you can enable.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/logging.html